# After image is deleted WordPress visual editor doesn't remove additional code that I added to default img html output via image_send_to_editor filter

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to replace the default image html output in WordPress editor with responsive images picture tag.
I created a custom function that replaces the default img html and hooked it into editor via image_send_to_editor filter:

```
function mystic_responsive_insert_image($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url) {
    $image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $image_url );
    $alt_text = get_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
    if ( !$alt_text ) { $alt_text = esc_html( get_the_title($post_id) ); }      
    $thumb_xl_hpt1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'xl-thumb-hpt1');
    $thumb_lg_hpt1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'lg-thumb-hpt1');
    $thumb_md_hpt1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'md-thumb-hpt1'); 
    $thumb_sm_hpt1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'sm-thumb-hpt1');
    $thumb_xs_hpt1 = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'xs-thumb-hpt1');              
    $thumb_xl_hpt1_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'xl-thumb-hpt1-2x');
    $thumb_lg_hpt1_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'lg-thumb-hpt1-2x');
    $thumb_md_hpt1_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'md-thumb-hpt1-2x'); 
    $thumb_sm_hpt1_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'sm-thumb-hpt1-2x');
    $thumb_xs_hpt1_2x = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'xs-thumb-hpt1-2x');    
    $thumb_data = array(                    
        'thumb_xl_hpt1_2x'          => $thumb_xl_hpt1_2x[0],
        'thumb_large_hpt1_2x'   => $thumb_lg_hpt1_2x[0], 
        'thumb_medium_hpt1_2x'  => $thumb_md_hpt1_2x[0],
        'thumb_small_hpt1_2x'   => $thumb_sm_hpt1_2x[0],
        'thumb_xs_hpt1_2x'      => $thumb_xs_hpt1_2x[0],                    
        'thumb_xl_hpt1'             => $thumb_xl_hpt1[0],
        'thumb_large_hpt1'    => $thumb_lg_hpt1[0], 
        'thumb_medium_hpt1'   => $thumb_md_hpt1[0],
        'thumb_small_hpt1'    => $thumb_sm_hpt1[0],
        'thumb_xs_hpt1'         => $thumb_xs_hpt1[0],
        'thumb_alt'                     => $alt_text
    );

    $html = '<picture>';
    $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->';
    $html .= '<source srcset="' . $thumb_data['thumb_xl_hpt1'] . ', ' . $thumb_data['thumb_xl_hpt1_2x'] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 1200px)">';
    $html .= '<source srcset="' . $thumb_data['thumb_large_hpt1'] . ', ' . $thumb_data['thumb_large_hpt1_2x'] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 992px)">';
    $html .= '<source srcset="' . $thumb_data['thumb_medium_hpt1'] . ', ' . $thumb_data['thumb_medium_hpt1_2x'] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 768px)">';
    $html .= '<source srcset="' . $thumb_data['thumb_small_hpt1'] . ', ' . $thumb_data['thumb_small_hpt1_2x'] . ' 2x" media="(min-width: 576px)">';
    $html .= '<!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->';
    $html .= '<img srcset="' . $thumb_data['thumb_xs_hpt1'] . ', ' . $thumb_data['thumb_xs_hpt1_2x'] . ' 2x" alt="' . $thumb_data['thumb_alt'] . '">';
    $html .= '</picture>';
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'image_send_to_editor', 'mystic_responsive_insert_image', 10, 9 );
```

I then created a test post and inserted the image into it to see if my code works. It does. But then after I deleted the image and inserted another one, inside the chrome inspector I noticed that the additional html code from the deleted image is still present on the page. Everything except the img tag that was placed inside the picture tag is still there. Deleting the image from the editor removed only the img tag.
I'm making this for someone who is not familiar with html and I'm certain that they will not be able to delete the leftover code from the text editor if they ever edit the images in their posts so I need to figure out why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using any caching plugins and if so, have you tried purging these caches?

Comment: I'm using w3 total cache but it's disabled at the moment. The strange thing is that this thing kinda got resolved all by itself because it doesn't seem to happen anymore. I'm not sure if it's something I did or whatever but I just tried editing the post again and now there is no more leftover code after I delete and replace an image.

Comment: My best guess is that it is due to your browser cache then - should it happen again you could try to delete it and see if that solves it.

Comment: I don't think it was due to browser cache because the leftover code was still present in the database and it was visible in worpress text editor. It's strange that it got resolved all by itself but important thing is that it works now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because while removing image, visual editor only removes image in img tag and rest of the HTML is still there. On updating, it updates the HTML in database.
Also, It appends previous HTML with new HTML.

You just have to filter data before it is saved. Have to remove 'picture' tag in which there is no image. You can use 'wp_insert_post_data' hook for this.